# AngularJS expression if value is in array

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to add a class to an element if a value is in an array within the scope, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code:

```
$scope.weather = [];
$scope.cool = ['Cool'];
$scope.mild = ['Mild'];
$scope.hot = ['Hot'];

$scope.selectWeather = function(weatherType){
    if($.inArray(weatherType, $scope.weather) == -1){
        $scope.weather.push(weatherType);
    }else{
        $scope.weather.splice($.inArray(weatherType, $scope.weather),1);
    }       
}



<a class="cool" ng-click="selectWeather('Cool');" ng-class="{'selected': cool.$indexOf(weather) != -1}">
    Cool
</a>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide the demo?

Comment: `$indexOf` is probably not a function.

Comment: What is output of: `cool.$indexOf(weather)`? try: `<pre>{{cool.$indexOf(weather)}}</pre>`

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing and I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Can you check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L4a14uz/) and tell me if it does what you want? I will post an answer with explanations then.

Comment: @muenchdo - That works! It was the inArray that was causing the problem.  Many thanks for your help on that.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @muenchdo - do you want to put your answer on here so i can mark it as correct?  At leas you get the recognition for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `$indexOf()` inside your `ng-class`, which is not a function. Just use the regular `indexOf` in your template like this:

```
<a class="cool" 
   ng-click="selectWeather('Cool')"
   ng-class="{'selected': weather.indexOf('Cool') != -1}">Cool</a>
```

Your `selectWeather` function was also not quite correct:

```
$scope.selectWeather = function (weatherType) {
  if ($scope.weather.indexOf(weatherType) == -1) {
    $scope.weather.push(weatherType);
  } else {
    $scope.weather.splice($scope.weather.indexOf(weatherType), 1);
  }       
}
```

There are also some other issues with your code which I fixed in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L4a14uz/).